# I'm having an issue with my Contact Form overflowing when displayed on a mobile

Tags: html, css, forms, footer, contacts

The issue is basically that whenever I have this form displayed on a mobile phone, when i go to input text into the form, the textarea expands too much and goes over the Submit button and the footer. when i click outside of the textarea, it stays expanded, but the submit button and footer return to their places below the textarea. What am I doing wrong? I've provided here the html and the css. What is it that could cause something like that to happen and how can i fix it?

All i want it to do is stay a reasonable size. It doesn't seem to have any issue when loaded on a desktop. It only seems to happen on mobile phones.

THIS IS THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" /> </head>

<body>
  <form action="success.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return     validateTextbox();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> Full Name:
    <input id="fullname" name="name" type="text" value="" size="40" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
    <br>
    <br> Your Email:
    <input id="youremail" name="email" type="email" value="" size="40" placeholder="Enter your Email" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <!--How do you want your transcript?<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="transcript_type" value="verbatim"/>Verbatim
<input type="radio" name="transcript_type" value="non_verbatim"/>Non-  Verbatim
<input type="radio" name="transcript_type" value="unknown"/>Don't Know  Yet<br><br>-->Your Message:
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="messageArea" name="message" rows="40" cols="80" placeholder="Enter your message here (10 character minimum.)"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return val();" /> </form>
</body>

</html>
```

THIS IS THE CSS

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
form {
    /*border-style: solid;
border-right-style: none;
border-left-style: none;*/

    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(images/starbright_avw.png);
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
}
label {
    font-family: impact;
}
/* 
text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;*/

input[type="submit"] {
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.row {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
p.message {} p.yourMessage {
    font-family: impact;
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide a screenshot?

Comment: http://i63.tinypic.com/w7yhio.png and http://i66.tinypic.com/2n7jtpy.png these are what the form looks like on mobile phones after I've begun inputting text into them.

Comment: It seems like if you give it a fixed height like `height: 686px`,  it would not be expended. I am still looking into it.

Comment: Thanks alooot.... giving it a fixed height worked. But I almost swear I tried it before and it didn't work. Weird. But thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be caused by the mobile website viewport zooming. Once you type any character in the textarea, the mobile viewport zooming would enlarge the line-height by 10px, which increases the height of the textarea by cols * 10px. In your code, it grows another 400px. I have two solution for this.

1. Setting a fixed height for the textarea. As to your situation, you can set the height of the textarea to `cols` * `line-height`. Say your line-height of the text is 18px and `cols="40"`, you can set `height:18*40=720px;`.
2. You can add:

   `<head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /></head>`

and set the width of the textarea as 100%.